# Monitoring network activity

Tags: c++, windows, network-programming

I wanted to know if there was a way (APIs , Library) to monitor network activity on different interfaces (wireless , wired) being performed by applications triggered by different users on windows.

Comment: sounds like you're asking about the [PCAP](http://www.winpcap.org/) library?  it's something that is typically installed with [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on windoze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a program that can monitor various interfaces, log packets, and filter them based upon packet addressing, protocol, etc.

Look at the program called Wireshark/Ethereal (using Pcap), or Tcpdump.

Comment: I am looking at pcap. That sounds easy to use for windows

Comment: Yes, you will need admin rights.  It puts your interface into promiscuous mode.

Comment: Is it possible to redirect packets using pcap ?

Comment: You want a proxy server for that.